# Custom ItemDelegate for QListView in PySide: Items invisible

Tags: python-3.x, pyside, qlistview, qstyleditemdelegate

### Question:

Why does the Python-equivalent of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729858/override-text-in-qstyleditemdelegate-for-qtreeview#35199113) answer

```
class CustomDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        opt = QtGui.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        self.initStyleOption(opt, index)
        opt.text = "Test Text"
        QtGui.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, opt, painter)
```

not draw anything into my listview, while I can draw various other widgets with arbitrary labeling by passing the right `QStyleOption` including necessary members and the `text`-member set to the desired text like so:

```
class CustomDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        opt = QtGui.QStyleOptionButton()
        opt.rect = option.rect
        opt.text = "Test Text"
        QtGui.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_PushButton, opt, painter)
```

---

### Problem Background:

In PySide I have a `QFileSystemModel` applied to a `QListView` and want to display the file names without the file extensions.
My plan was to apply a `CustomDelegate` which inherits `QStyledItemDelegate` and to alter the text member of a `QStyleOptionViewItem` inside the `paint()`-function just as you can see in my first code sample above. Only difference: `"Test Text"` is replaced by `os.path.splitext(index.data())[0]`.

Although the items get inserted into the listview, (I can tell by the appearing scroll bar and by clicking anywhere in the list and printing the active item) the items are not painted at all and stay invisible.

The same happens if I don't try to alter anything and pass the original `option`-parameter:

```
class CustomDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        QtGui.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, option, painter)
```

---

### Further Info:

If I just call the super-`paint()`-function, the items are displayed normally:

```
class CustomDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
```

That gave me the idea to pass my own `opt` to the super-`paint()`:

```
class CustomDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        opt = QtGui.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        self.initStyleOption(opt, index)
        opt.text = os.path.splitext(index.data())[0]
        print(opt.text)
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, opt, index)
```

but this displays the file names **with** extensions as well... although the `print()` puts the names to the console **without** extensions.

Strangly, trying to print `opt.text` **before** setting it to anything gets me:

```
AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QStyleOptionViewItem' object has no attribute 'text'
```

And last: Leaving out the `initStyleOption()`-call doesn't seem to make any difference in any configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a way to achieve my goal. I still don't know why my `CustomDelegate` behaves in such a weird and illogical manner, but I realized that I could tackle my problem in an earlier stage and implement a custom `QFileSystemModel` to assign to my `QListView`:

```
class CustomFileSystemModel(QtGui.QFileSystemModel):
    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return os.path.splitext(QtGui.QFileSystemModel.data(self, index, role))[0]
        else:
            return QtGui.QFileSystemModel.data(self, index, role)
```

That way I can just drop my `CustomDelegate` and the standard `QStyledItemDelegate` assigned to the `QListView` per default gets the already shortened file names passed. I think that is an even more elegant way, but it is still unsatisfying to not know about what's going on with this `CustomDelegate`. So if someone ever finds a *real* answer to all that, I would really appreciate her/him sharing it!